# Make sure your project build settings are generating a dSYM file. DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for all configurations

Tags: xcode, debugging, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've recently started getting this error:

```
2015-03-23 11:35:48.902 run[60036:1047011] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.14
2015-03-23 11:35:48.911 run[60036:1047011] 

Crashlytics: dSYM Error

Unable to process <your app>.app.dSYM at path /path/to/<your app>.app.dSYM
Make sure your project build settings are generating a dSYM file. DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for all configurations. This could also be a timing issue, make sure the Crashlytics run script build phase is the last build phase and no other scripts have moved the dSYM from the location Xcode generated it.

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I tried this answer [Unable to copy dSYM file into archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466095/unable-to-copy-dsym-file-into-archive) but all my `Generate Debug Symbols` are set to `YES`

Any further suggestions?

Comment: IMHO this is a nuisance on behalf of Fabric. We specifically disable dsym from debug configurations to speed up builds.

Comment: Want to have a cake and eat it, too? Set DWARF only for Simulator. http://holko.pl/2016/10/18/dsym-debug/

Comment: App build failed with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630429/app-build-failed-in-xcode-with-continuing-in-background-failed-to-display-xcode. Can anyone know solution for my question

Answer (score 639):

The below solution worked for me.

Go to build setting of your project, then Search for debug information format in build setting and search for "Debug information format" then set **"Debug information format" to "DWARF with dSYM file"**

[image]

and make sure **Generate debug symbol** in build setting is set to Yes.

Comment: In my case, this setting was `DWARF` for Debug mode. Setting it to `DWARF with dSYM` made the warning go away. Thanks!

Comment: weeeeell, what if I would like to speed up my build time while I Run things in DEBUG (by turning off dSym generation at end of build process)? I wanna disable this warning. Gotto find the script!

Comment: @Jaro: I'm looking into something similar. In this blog post they also changed that setting for each cocoapod, do you think that is necessary too? https://tech.zalando.com/blog/speeding-up-xcode-builds/

Comment: @fabb: thanks for the script but it did not work out for me. After pods are being installed I still see dSYM.

Hell with this "cocoapods vs dSYM off" thing, makes no difference  in build time if you have 100+ files in the project to compile. Same results: 30 sec.

Now a 2 SSD in RAID 0 makes a difference :)

Comment: Or maybe a ramdrive http://blog.shpakovski.com/2014/02/how-to-reduce-xcode-and-appcode.html?m=1

Comment: If I set it to "DWARF with dSYM File" for Release, does it mean I'm shipping debug symbols to customers, who can use it to reverse-engineer my app?

Comment: @VaddadiKartick no, it means the release build will produce dSYM artifacts that can be used to symbolicate crashes in your shipping app.  These symbols files are not exposed to your customers.

Furthermore, once you submit your app, new "thinned" symbols files are produced for the various supported architectures and pixel densities.  So the symbols files you generate on your build won't even work on the shipped app.

Comment: This may slow down your debug building speed. I suggest to jump the Crashlytics scripts if you are running in debug mode. Use something like this: `debugConfig="Debug"
if [ "$debugConfig" != "${CONFIGURATION}" ]; then
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" fi`

Comment: Yeah, right, but after you check this "DWARF with dSYM file" -- you start receiving messages from App Store : "Too many symbol files"

Comment: Where can I find the equivalent in visual studio for xamarin.iOS app development?

Answer (score 98):

Check for true "run script only when installing" on Run Script

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: it do with install script of Fabric be execute during app install. This will correct the DYSM problems

Comment: @Bruno I understand you know that this will correct the DSYM problems. Why is that the case, though? Does it correct this problem by introducing another? What does it actually do which corrects the problem?

Answer (score 8):

Elaborating Bruno's response, if you already have a script phase that you need to run all the time, create a new dedicated phase in order to avoid conflicts.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I removed Fabric and Crashlytics and added them back again from the beginning just like I were to install it the first time around. It worked.

see also https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-reinstall-fabric-crashlytics/37890

Comment: I has no Twitter account and don't want to sign up there. Can you show that solution here? At least main part.