# IOS App crashes on Iphone

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently experiencing a problem where the app crashes when you are trying to open it. Any ideas on how to decode the IOS Crash log, i've attached a small section of the crash log below.

```
Date/Time:           2018-08-28 11:03:06.6413 +0100
Launch Time:         2018-08-28 11:03:05.6498 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    2.03.12
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  5

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x182512d8c 0x1816cc5ec 0x182512bf8 0x182f0300c 0x18d206adc 0x18d1dfb74 0x18d224c8c 0x18d226978 0x18d240dd0 0x18d24076c 0x182e929b0 0x18d2423d0 0x18d241e7c 0x18d242398 0x18c3edc08 0x102f41034 0x103a8825c 0x103a87c24 0x103a0341c 0x1039f4034 0x103aff8fc 0x103aff938 0x182f5defc 0x182139220 0x182139110 0x182137b10)
```

Any thoughts on how to determine what the issue is?

Comment: Do you have a paid developer membership?  If not, how long ago did you last compile the app and install it?

Comment: For decode crash log require **Debug Information Format** refer
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209582/make-sure-your-project-build-settings-are-generating-a-dsym-file-debug-informat

Comment: @Paulw11 yes i have paid developer membership. The app is an existing app already available on the play store, so one of my users report the app crashes everytime they try and open it. So i received the crash log from the user.

Comment: @ShankarShinde i'll take a look