# App build failed in xcode with Continuing in background (Failed to display Xcode notification) due to the sentry

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, osascript, react-native-sentry

Unable to build my app suddenly. This is the error which I got after running the **caused by: script error: osascript: no such component "JavaScript".**

```
  Continuing in background.

       Error: Failed to display Xcode notification
          caused by: script error: osascript: no such component "JavaScript".

        /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dvcafjcjvuogulagizfflouagntd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Script-00199139199199133.sh: line 5: debug]: command not found
Add --log-level=[info|debug] or export SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=[info|debug] to see more output.
Please attach the full debug log to all bug reports
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to build in Xcode. It will give you exact error.

Comment: I am building from xcode only. The above error is from Xcode

Comment: Could you please send me an entire screenshot?